# How do you use ranged weapons on the ipad version of Brogue

Tags: ios, brogue

On the computer version of brogue you can use ranged weapons by using the mouse, but I can't work out how to do it on the iPad version. Whenever I try to do it on the iPad version by tapping on an enemy, I just end up moving towards the enemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the items menu you have the choice to "drop" and "throw" items. Select "throw" and you can chuck your darts at enemies to do some meagre damage